Reference request for a formalization of circular arguments
Has any philosopher or mathematician formalized the notion of circular arguments? I know what a circular argument is, informally, but I am wondering if anyone has gave a rigorous definition of it. If so, I would like to see some references.

Woods-Walton, Arresting Circles in Formal Dialogues:"Circular reasoning can be studied by means of three distinct kinds of system. They are: (i) Systems of doxastic-epistemic logic such as may be found in the work of Kripke, Hintikka, and Wu; (ii) systems of formal dialectic or formal dialogues as represented by Hamblin and Lorenzen; and (iii) such non-intensional, non-game-theoretic standard approaches as are afforded by first-order logic. De Morgan presents the first systematic case for an approach to the petitio in the style of (iii)."

Turns out that this question is (practically) a duplicate of https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/is-circular-reasoning-always-a-fallacy

A "circular argument" ("begging the question", petitio principii) is an argument in which the conclusion is assumed as one of the premisses. Since the conclusion is assumed, the argument is logically valid. But it's pointless or unacceptable for the same reason. We usually only want to accept an argument if it's both valid and sound (all unargued premisses are true) and if the conclusion is not already assumed as one of the unargued premisses.
So the overall formal structure is simple:

(p1, p2, ... pk) ⊢ pi  (with 1 <= i <= k)

This is clearly valid (since it reduces to 'p ⊢ p'), but not acceptable as actual demonstration or proof of pi. So, it's not a logical fallacy, but a pragmatical fallacy (making a deduction is robbed of its purpose). When we speak of "begging the question", we also highlight the pragmatics (the fact that an argument is given in the context of a dispute or as answer to a question).
See: SEP entry for Fallacies under "begging the question".
For a closer look at possible formalizations of informal arguments (taking the pragmatics into account) see also Are Circular Arguments Necessarily Vicious (1985) by D.N. Walton. The upshot is that not all arguments that appear to be circular are fallacious or vicious. After all, eggs do produce chickens and chickens do lay eggs.

Circular arguments may in informal contexts not be directly obvious, but for a logician they are not very interesting (they are simply too simple if you leave the pragmatics out). What is much more interesting is a generalization of "circularity" in terms of "vicious circles".
In order to prevent Russel's paradox in set theory, Russell and Whitehead proposed the Vicious Circle Principle which can be stated as

No object or class can be defined in terms of itself, or by any totality to which it belongs.

In other words, a "vicious circle" definition of some object is one that does define it in terms of itself or of the totality to which it belongs. In informal contexts we do seem to be violating this principle very often. For instance, consider this definition

A proposition is anything that can be true or false.

Seems rather innocent, right? But we should be wary of this definition, since it itself can also be read as proposition, and if we do that, we are then defining "proposition" with an implicit reference to a totality (which includes that very proposition). (See the SEP link for the full quote.)
It's not completely clear whether or not the vicious circle principle is really needed to avoid paradoxes like Russell's barber. In A Universal Approach to Self-Referential Paradoxes, Incompleteness and Fixed Points (2003), Noson Yanofsky puts this as open question:

Since we can generate the same paradoxes without self-reference, does this destroy Russell’s vicious-circle principle?


+1 " After all, eggs do produce chickens and chickens do lay eggs." I have always felt that circularity is a logical virtue of a sorts. Impredicativity also has utility.
